# Running MS Access Programs as exe

Tags: ms-access

I have read somewhere that you can run ms access programs as independent exes but you have to have ms access runtime.Question is,how can i bundle ms access runtime  with my ms access program and can i also bundle a database of my choice i.e mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the first question here :

http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/developereditionfaq.htm

EDIT :

You can use linked tables in your access application, and yes, it is possible to link to mysql tables. A way to do this is setting up an ODBC connection to your mysql tables and use that connection to link to your tables.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of a way to compile Access apps into EXEs, but you can obtain a Developer Edition of Access from Microsoft which allows you to distribute the Access runtime files along with your program. Your users don't need to have Access installed in order to use your program. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb229700.aspx

Comment: Will it be possible to use my own database like mysql instead of linq

Comment: As Peter has pointed out in the meantime: Yes, you can use linked tables. You will have to make sure that the other database (i.e. MySQL) is installed and/or accessible on your customer's machine.

Comment: There has not been a "developer edition" of Access for a long time. The runtime has been free to download since A2007.